# SwiftUI Full Screen Width Content Within Form

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-form, swiftui-scrollview

How can I have a `Form` with one element in the `Form` taking up the full screen width?
I tried putting the `Form` into a `ScrollView` but then there are other issues and it might not be a good idea to nest 2 scrolling views.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Text("Other content of Form")
            Section {
                Image(systemName: "pencil.circle.fill")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .listRowInsets(.none)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is how it looks now:
[image: Starting Layout]

And this is what I want it to look:
[image: Desired Layout]

Comment: I ran your code, and it produces a full-width view. What's the desired behavior, here? What's not right?

Comment: set form padding to ```.padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: -25, bottom: 0, trailing: -25))```

Comment: @West1 If you run it on narow iPhone (like SE1), the `Form` has no horizontal margin there - might this be the case?

Comment: @RajaKishan This doesn't work - first, a specific paddding value would break eg. on iPad, second, a Form still seems to crop the item to fit its boundaries no matter the padding.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to do a `ScrollView` and inset + style the child elements instead.